# Problem with page navigation C# WPF with obfuscation (Memory)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making an app which includes pages with sizes around 200 mb each due to parsing a lot of information and UI thing.

I'm trying to reuse created page to not use a lot of memory.

For some reason garbage collector not releasing memory.

I could not find a way to navigate to a new page without creating new instance of page.

I've got a singleton NavigationManager.

```
internal class NavigationManager
    {
        private static NavigationManager _instance;
        public static NavigationManager Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new NavigationManager();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        private NavigationManager()
        {
            
        }

        private List<Page> pages = new();
        private Page temporaryPage;
        
        public void NavigateTo(string pageName, MainWindow mainWindow)
        {          
            if (pages.Any(p => p.Name == pageName))
            {
                mainWindow.MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(pages.First(p => p.Name == pageName));
            }
            else
            {
                temporaryPage = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType($"MyApp.MVVM.View.{pageName}"));
                pages.Add(temporaryPage);
                mainWindow.MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(temporaryPage);
            }
        }
    }
```

And navigating just using:

```
NavigationManager.Instance.NavigateTo(@"MainPages.MainPage", this);
```

But here after obfuscation I can't use Type.GetType with strings because it won't just find it.Without obfuscation it works fine.

Is there a way to clear, delete, remove a page?

Or maybe use Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType()) more properly with obfuscation.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you want to get thy type by name, you need to exclude it from renaming by the Obfuscator, e.g. by applying `[Obfuscation(Exclude=true)]` to it.

Comment: @KlausGütter yeah, but if so I need to exclude it from 20+ pages which is not good

Comment: The frame will tend to latch onto pages. Frame and page are a bad choice if you are concerned about garbage collecting what you navigate to. Usercontrol are better. Use a contentpresenter content to show one.

Comment: You know obfuscation is near pointless? Just makes it slightly harder to understand decompiled code.

Comment: How does the user choose what they navigate to? You could possibly use reflection and attributes to find all your pages.

Comment: @Andy I've got 50+ usercontrols cuz it's a huge project. One page includes 10+ usercontrols so it's better to use page instead of usercontrols. Maybe I'm wrong tho

Comment: @Andy I have buttons on the left side of UI, navigation just by clicking, tried to use commands but due to custom buttons and wpf sucks on some parts I had to just make click events for each buttons to navigate

Comment: You can encapsulate as much or as little as you like in a usercontrol. I've used the approach I describe in very big commercial apps.

Comment: You could dynamically discover your types. Write an attribute you add to anything you want in your navigation list.  That would have DisplayName or some such as a parameter. 
 Iterate through your pages dll using reflection to create a list of display name and type. And you can then instantiate from type.

Comment: This is viewmodel first navigation which I would recommend. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx  You could dynamically build that list of TypeAndDisplay that's bound to the itemscontrol itemssource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need to keep the page type names obfuscated, as you note you can't use `Type.GetType` with a string. Instead you can do something even easier - just pass in the `Type`. Your `NavigateTo` method would look something like this:

```
    public void NavigateTo(Type pageType, MainWindow mainWindow)
    {          
        var existing = pages.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.GetType() == pageType);
        if (existing != null)
        {
            mainWindow.MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(existing);
        }
        else
        {
            temporaryPage = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
            pages.Add(temporaryPage);
            mainWindow.MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(temporaryPage);
        }
    }
```

To call it you'd say

```
 NavigationManager.Instance.NavigateTo(typeof(MainPages.MainPage), this);
```

By using `typeof` and passing around `Type` objects you're safe from obfuscation because your code no longer cares about what things are named. It's better practice even without obfuscation to be honest.

Unfortunately I don't see a way around some refactoring here but this should require the least amount of it.